# How can I execute this function using VBA in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, vba

I'm trying to get this function in VBA but I'm new to it. I don't seem to know how I can get this done:

What I'm trying to do is, for each cell in column B that's numeric, I want to take the next two cells in column H i.e if it's B7, I'd like to take H8 and H9 (next two row values in H column) and concatenate them (they're strings) and save them in I7 (same row as B7) and finally delete the values in H8,H9.

Here's where I got to, I know it isn't much.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim B As Range, H As Range, I As Range
For Each B In ClientTable.Columns(2).Cells
    If IsNumeric(B) Then
    (What should be done here?)    
    End If
Next B
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found `IsNumeric(B)` to be true for blank cells,
so I changed your `If` statement accordingly.  This worked for me:

```
    If IsNumeric(B) And B <> "" Then
        Cells(B.Row, 9) = Cells(B.Row + 1, 8) & Cells(B.Row + 2, 8)
        Cells(B.Row + 1, 8) = ""
        Cells(B.Row + 2, 8) = ""
    End If
    If B.Row > 9 Then Exit For
```

Obviously `8` and `9` are the column numbers for `H` and `I`, respectively. 
I added the

```
If B.Row > 9 Then Exit For
```

line because I had a problem with the loop not terminating; if

```
For Each B In ClientTable.Columns(2).Cells
```

works for you, you can take out the `If B.Row > 9 Then Exit For`.

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm! I just tweaked it a little bit so as not to have problem with the ClientTable.Columns(2).Cells
`Sub Clasgers()

Dim B As Range, H As Range, I As Range

For Each B In Range("B7:B49").Cells

    If IsNumeric(B) And B <> "" Then

        Cells(B.Row, 9) = Cells(B.Row + 1, 8) & Cells(B.Row + 2, 8)

        Cells(B.Row + 1, 8) = ""

        Cells(B.Row + 2, 8) = ""

        If B.Row > 50 Then Exit For

    End If

Next B

End Sub`

Thanks though.

Comment: Also there are spaces in between the words in the cells in column I that is created here. Is there a way to remove those spaces, any spaces in column I?

Comment: Try `newVal = Replace(oldVal, " ", "")`, e.g., `Cells(B.Row, 9) = Replace(Cells(B.Row+1, 8) & Cells(B.Row+2, 8), " ", "")`.

Comment: Thanks again. I got it by Cells(B.Row, 9) = Trim(Cells(B.Row + 1, 8)) & Trim(Cells(B.Row + 2, 8)) but I'll keep that in mind :)

Comment: If an answer helps you, you can acknowledge that [by “accepting” it](http://superuser.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the check mark next to it.  Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful.